# How can I debug why my single-job pod ends with status = "Error"?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm setting up a Kubernetes cluster and am testing a small container. This is my YAML file for the pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: node
    image: 'node:5'
    command: ['node']
    args: ['-e', 'console.log(1234)']
```

I deploy it with `kubectl create -f example.yml` and sure enough it runs as expected:

```
$ kubectl logs example
1234
```

However, the pod's status is "Error":

```
$ kubectl get po example
NAME           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
example        0/1       Error     0          16m
```

How can I investigate why the status is "Error"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`kubectl describe pod example` will give you more info on what's going on

also

`kubectl get events` can get you more details too although not dedicated to the given pod.

Comment: Thanks. Kubernetes shows the pod status as Succeeded and the container's state as Terminated, with the reason being Error and exit code being 0. So looks like things are actually working as expected.